# Change Material Image/Texture from Sphere with Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to change Image/Texture from Sphere that is Material with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in a new script and add it to your Object as a Component:

C#:

```
class MaterialSetter : MonoBehaviour{
    public void SetMaterial(Material newMaterial)
    {
        Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        renderer.material = newMaterial;
    }
}
```

You can call SetMaterial from any other script, provided you have the reference to your target object. You could, for example, set the material at the beginning of your game adding a Start() function to your MaterialSetter class:

C#:

```
class MaterialSetter : MonoBehaviour{
    public Material StartMaterial;

    // ...
    void Start()
    {
        SetMaterial(StartMaterial);
    }
}
```

Now if you want to set the Material by name, your Material needs to be in the folder Assets/Resources. Everything you get via Resources.Load, must be located in that folder. Then the code would look like this:

C#:

```
class MaterialSetter : MonoBehaviour{
    public void SetMaterial(string materialName)
    {
        Material mat = Resources.Load(materialName, typeof(Material)) as Material;
        Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        renderer.material = newMaterial;
    }
}
```

If you want to change the texture used in your material (assuming you use the Unity Standard Shader) you'll have to get a texture by reference or from your resources, if you want to get it by name:

C#:

```
public void SetTexture(string textureName)
{
    Texture tex = Resources.Load(textureName, typeof(Texture)) as Texture;
    Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    renderer.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", tex);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain me or make it C# cause I'm not so good with Javascript what newMaterial is and all other..thanks for the help

Comment: Oh, I assumed you would code in "Javascript" (which isn't real JS, it's UnityScript ;) ), since you added unityscript as a tag. I'll add c# code to my original answer. newMaterial is the parameter, you provide to the function SetMaterial. It's the Material you want to assign to your object. If you have problems understanding the above code, I would advise you to spend some time with C# (or any language) and gather some understanding about concepts like function calls. It's worth the effort :)

Comment: Thank you so much and please tell what newMaterial is and other so I can make it work

Comment: I know any language I just don't know so much about Unity

Comment: That's alright. Sorry for my impolite assumptions on your programming knowledge. I'll add some more clarifications to the answer.